# uWSGI server works alright in my environment, not in a docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask app, that is run on uWSGI server. If I start it in my environment by:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

it works alright. The contents of uwsgi.ini is:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
protocol = http
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 5

socket = 127.0.0.1:3032
chmod-sock = 664
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

wsgi.py is:

```
from test2 import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Finally, my docker file is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY . /flask_app/
WORKDIR /flask_app

RUN apt-get clean \
&& apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev \
&& apt-get -y install python3-pip \
&& apt-get -y install build-essential

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]
```

I am new to docker, so please bear with me. When I create and run the image (sudo docker run -p 8000:3032 test), i see the same output as when starting the uWSGI server in my environment, the only difference is, when i try to go to the site localhost:8000 in my browser, nothing happens and I dont see any requests in the log of the containarized uWSGI server as opposed to when running from my environment.

What is my goal - I want to have a container, that I can deploy to some server to serve as an API for other containers.

All your help is much appreciated

Comment: Does changing `socket = 0.0.0.0:3032` help?  In general if you configure a server to listen on 127.0.0.1 in Docker, it won't be accessible from outside its own container.

Comment: Docker uses an internal network, you can't just listen to localhost: `127.0.0.1:3032` → `0.0.0.0:3032`.

Comment: When I do that, it stops working in my environment too and returns to me:
bind(): Cannot assign requested address [core/socket.c line 769]
The docker with this change behaves the same. Ifconfig gives me docker0 on 172.17.0.1/255.255.0.0, and when i tried putting socket = 172.17.0.1:3032, it had the same outcome

Comment: At a first glance I couldn't see any errors in what you have done. With your existing setup, have you tried typing `127.0.0.1:8000` or `0.0.0.0:8000` in the browser instead of localhost?